# Minimum value in 3D NumPy array along specified axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, minimum

Say you have a 3D array as follows:

```
a = np.random.uniform(0,10,(3,4,4))

a
Out[167]: 
array([[[6.11382489, 5.33572952, 2.6994938 , 5.32924568],
        [0.02494179, 9.5813176 , 3.78090323, 7.73698908],
        [0.4559432 , 3.14531716, 4.18929635, 9.44256735],
        [7.05641989, 0.51355523, 6.61806454, 1.3124488 ]],

       [[9.79806021, 6.9343234 , 3.96018673, 8.97424501],
        [3.25146771, 5.06744849, 6.05870707, 2.27286515],
        [4.66656429, 6.92791142, 7.1623226 , 5.34108811],
        [6.09831564, 9.52367529, 8.27257007, 8.01510805]],

       [[5.62545596, 9.01048599, 6.76713644, 7.71836144],
        [5.59842752, 0.34003062, 8.07114444, 8.5382837 ],
        [0.20420194, 6.39088367, 4.97895935, 4.26247875],
        [1.2701483 , 8.35244104, 2.69965027, 8.39305974]]])
```

Is there a way to get the minimum values in the slices along `axis=0` as one array efficiently?

So in this case I would specify `axis=0` (i.e. the axis with dimension length=3) and return the minimum values: `(0.02494179, 2.27286515, 0.20420194)`.

I feel like this is a simple problem but I can't seem to get it to work, so any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `np.min(a, axis=0)` not work? I'm not 100% sure why you would expect only 3 values.

Comment: Ah I just realised using np.min(a, axis=(1,2)) returns the values I'm after apologies I should have made it clearer that I was after the minimum values in each slice along a specified axis

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you just have to apply "min" twice

for instance:

```
>>> np.random.seed(1)  #reproduce the same results 
>>> a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,2,4)) #using int is easier to understand                                                                       
Out[4]: 
array([[[5, 8, 9, 5],
        [0, 0, 1, 7]],

       [[6, 9, 2, 4],
        [5, 2, 4, 2]],

       [[4, 7, 7, 9],
        [1, 7, 0, 6]]])

 >>> a.min(axis=0).min(axis=0)                                                                          
Out[5]: array([0, 0, 0, 2])
```

It is the first time I post an answer, I hope I did okay.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite right, as I would be looking for an output of ([0,2,0]) if I had the array you provided in your answer. What your solution does is calculate the minimum value in each column of your array. Thanks though!